# mono aspx not working, HTML working fine

Tags: asp.net, apache, ubuntu, mono

Ive managed to get an ubuntu server up, running apache and Mono, so that I can run asp.net websites.
I've ported a website that I build in visual studio, and am trying to access it using localhost in my browser.

when I navigate to localhost/index.html everything works fine, but when I rename the file to index.aspx I get this error:

The requested URL /index.aspx was not found on this server.

I've checked the installation of mono using mono-test-install and it seemed to be fine. So I'm guessing it may be a reference somewhere in a config file?
I've searched an can't find this anywhere. If someone could just give me some direction I'm sure I can track it down.

I'm using the most up to date packages for mono/mod-mono/Ubuntu (14.04)/apache2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured the auto-hosting for ASP .net mod_mono? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/ REad the "Easy configuration of Mod_Mono" part.

Comment: yep, basically if I use auto host I get the error above, where I just get a page saying the file could not be found.